# how to generate Narcissistic numbers faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm

The “Narcissistic numbers”, are n digit numbers where the sum of all the nth power of their digits is equal to the number.

So, `153` is a narcissistic number because `1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153`.

Now given N, find all Narcissistic numbers that are N digit length ?

**My Approach :** was to iterate over all numbers doing sum of powers of digits

and check if its the same number or not, and I per calculated the powers.

but that's not good enough, so is there any faster way ?!

**Update:**
In nature there is just 88 narcissistic numbers, and the largest is 39 digits long,
But I just need the numbers with length 12 or less.

**My Code :**

```
long long int powers[11][12];
// powers[x][y] is x^y. and its already calculated

bool isNarcissistic(long long int x,int n){
    long long int r = x;
    long long int sum = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n ; ++i){
        sum += powers[x%10][n];
        if(sum > r)
            return false;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return (sum == r);
}

void find(int n,vector<long long int> &vv){
    long long int start = powers[10][n-1];
    long long int end = powers[10][n];

    for(long long int i=start ; i<end ; ++i){
        if(isNarcissistic(i,n))
            vv.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the restriction on `N`? This is a very important piece of information.

Comment: It may be a better exercise to force this into a `constexpr` function...

Comment: How long is say 12 digit calculation taking?

Comment: @specialscope: With a naive algorithm like the above, the complexity is so bad that you will probably never get to know the results.

Comment: Ya I get the point, even if you did 1 iteration per number you would have to make 999,999,999,999 comparisions. So I get a feeling solving this problem efficiently will require something like hadoop.

Comment: [Here](http://penguin.ewu.edu/~trolfe/Armstrong/ArmstrongOpt.doc) is a link to a paper which discusses a few optimizations for this.

Comment: Don't wanna troll this thread, but i wonder who makes an effort to find pattens like these and why ? :)

Comment: here is the list of all Narcissistic/Armstrong number list at base 10 -> there are only 88 of them and first 10 of them are digits... I think it's better to just load those not calculate... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NarcissisticNumber.html, Ok didn't notice that the last answer has the same link...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below implements the idea of @Daniel Fischer. It duplicates the [table referenced at Mathworld](http://oeis.org/A005188) and then prints a few more 11-digit numbers and verifies that there are none with 12 digits as stated [here](http://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/n/n023.htm).

It would actually be simplier and probably a little faster to generate all possible *histograms* of non-increasing digit strings rather than the strings themselves.  By a histogram I mean a table indexed 0-9 of frequencies of the respective digit.  These can be compared directly without sorting.  But the code below runs in < 1 sec, so I'm not going to implement the histogram idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 12

// pwr[d][n] is d^n
long long pwr[10][MAX_DIGITS + 1];

// Digits and final index of number being considered.
int digits[MAX_DIGITS];
int m;

// Fill pwr.
void fill_tbls(void)
{
  for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
    pwr[d][0] = 1;
    for (int p = 1; p <= MAX_DIGITS; p++) 
      pwr[d][p] = pwr[d][p-1] * d;
  }
}

// qsort comparison for integers descending
int cmp_ints_desc(const void *vpa, const void *vpb)
{
  const int *pa = vpa, *pb = vpb;
  return *pb - *pa;
}

// Test current number and print if narcissistic.
void test(void)
{
  long long sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
    sum += pwr[digits[i]][m + 1];
  int sum_digits[MAX_DIGITS * 2];
  int n = 0;
  for (long long s = sum; s; s /= 10)
    sum_digits[n++] = s % 10;
  if (n == m + 1) {
    qsort(sum_digits, n, sizeof(int), cmp_ints_desc);
    if (memcmp(sum_digits, digits, n * sizeof(int)) == 0) 
      printf("%lld\n", sum);
  }
}

// Recursive generator of non-increasing digit strings.
// Calls test when a string is complete.
void gen(int i, int min, int max)
{
  if (i > m) 
    test();
  else {
    for (int d = min; d <= max; d++) {
      digits[i] = d;
      gen(i + 1, 0, d); 
    }
  }
}

// Fill tables and generate.
int main(void)
{
  fill_tbls();
  for (m = 0; m < MAX_DIGITS; m++)
    gen(0, 1, 9);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Since there are only 88 narcisstic numbers in total, you can just store them in a look up table and iterate over it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NarcissisticNumber.html

Comment: I think the whole point of the exercise is to get to those narcissistic number yourself.

Comment: @specialscope that's not specified in the question and SO isn't a homework-solving mechanism

Comment: aha,, i know that,, but i need to generate them at run time !!

Comment: @Rami: You didn't say that. This is definitely the most efficient solution to the problem ;)

Comment: This is so sad... so no fun left in finding Narcissistic numbers in base 10. What about other bases? The mathworld page says only ''A table of the largest known narcissistic numbers in various bases is given by Pickover (1995)'' so there might be something left for other bases?

Comment: @RamiJarrar if you need to generate them at run time, iterate over the table and print them.

Comment: @Krystian: the number of narcissistic numbers is limited for any base.

Comment: Yep, I think this is the best/effective solution

Answer (score 14):

Start from the other end. Iterate over the set of all nondecreasing sequences of `d` digits, compute the sum of the `d`-th powers, and check whether that produces (after sorting) the sequence you started with.

Since there are

9×10^(d-1)

`d`-digit numbers, but only

```
(10+d-1) `choose` d
```

nondecreasing sequences of `d` digits, that reduces the search space by a factor close to `d!`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a program in Lua which found all the narcissistic numbers in 30829.642 seconds.  The basis of the program is a recursive digit-value count array generator function which calls a checking function when it's generated the digit-value count for all the digit-values.  Each nested loop iterates:

FROM i=
The larger of 0 and the solution to a+x*d^o+(s-x)*(d-1)^o >= 10^(o-1) for x
where 
 - 'a' is the accumulative sum of powers of digits so far,
 - 'd' is the current digit-value (0-9 for base 10),
 - 'o' is the total number of digits (which the sum of the digit-value count array must add up to),
 - 's' represents the remaining slots available until the array adds to 'o'

UP TO i<=
The smaller of 's' and the solution to a+x*d^o < 10^o for x with the same variables.

This ensures that the numbers checked will ALWAYS have the same number of digits as 'o', and therefore be more likely to be narcissistic while avoiding unnecessary computation.

In the loop, it does the recursive call for which it decrements the digit-value 'd' adds the current digit-value's contribution (a=a+i*d^o) and takes the i digit-slots used up away from 's'.

The gist of what I wrote is:

```
local function search(o,d,s,a,...) --Original number of digits, digit-value, remaining digits, accumulative sum, number of each digit-value in descending order (such as 5 nines)
    if d>0 then
        local d0,d1=d^o,(d-1)^o
        local dd=d0-d1
        --a+x*d^o+(s-x)*(d-1)^o >= 10^(o-1) , a+x*d^o < 10^o
        for i=max(0,floor((10^(o-1)-s*d1-a)/dd)),min(s,ceil((10^o-a)/dd)-1) do
            search(o,d-1,s-i,a+i*d0,i,...) --The digit counts are passed down as extra arguments.
        end
    else
        --Check, with the count of zeroes set to 's', if the sum 'a' has the same count of each digit-value as the list specifies, and if so, add it to a list of narcissists.
    end
end

local digits=1 --Skip the trivial single digit narcissistic numbers.
while #found<89 do
    digits=digits+1
    search(digits,9,digits,0)
end
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my program finds 89 narcissistic numbers!  These are what it finds:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208, 9474, 54748, 92727, 93084, 548834, 1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315, 24678050, 24678051, 88593477, 146511208, 472335975, 534494836, 912985153, 4679307774, 32164049650, 32164049651, 40028394225, 42678290603, 44708635679, 49388550606, 82693916578, 94204591914, 28116440335967, 4338281769391370, 4338281769391371, 21897142587612075, 35641594208964132, 35875699062250035, 1517841543307505039, 3289582984443187032, 4498128791164624869, 4929273885928088826, 63105425988599693916, 128468643043731391252,449177399146038697307, 21887696841122916288858, 27879694893054074471405, 27907865009977052567814, 28361281321319229463398, 35452590104031691935943, 174088005938065293023722, 188451485447897896036875, 239313664430041569350093, 1550475334214501539088894, 1553242162893771850669378, 3706907995955475988644380, 3706907995955475988644381, 4422095118095899619457938, 121204998563613372405438066, 121270696006801314328439376, 128851796696487777842012787, 174650464499531377631639254, 177265453171792792366489765, 14607640612971980372614873089, 19008174136254279995012734740, 19008174136254279995012734741, 23866716435523975980390369295, 1145037275765491025924292050346, 1927890457142960697580636236639, 2309092682616190307509695338915, 17333509997782249308725103962772, 186709961001538790100634132976990, 186709961001538790100634132976991, 1122763285329372541592822900204593, 12639369517103790328947807201478392, 12679937780272278566303885594196922, 1219167219625434121569735803609966019, 12815792078366059955099770545296129367, 115132219018763992565095597973971522400, 115132219018763992565095597973971522401
```

Answer (score 2):

For posterity ;-)  This is most similar to @Krakow10's approach, generating bags of digits recursively, starting with 9, then 8, then 7 ... to 0.

It's Python3 code and finds all base-10 solutions with 1 through 61 digits (the first "obviously impossible" width) in less than 10 minutes (on my box).  It's by far the fastest code I've ever heard of for this problem.  What's the trick?  No trick - just tedium ;-)  As we go along, the partial sum so far yields a world of constraints on feasible continuations.  The code just pays attention to those, and so is able to cut off vast masses of searches early.

Note:  this doesn't find 0.  I don't care.  While all the references say there are 88 solutions, their tables all have 89 entries.  Some eager editor must have added "0" later, and then everyone else mindlessly copied it ;-)

**EDIT** New version is over twice as fast, by exploiting some partial-sum constraints earlier in the search - now finishes in a little over 4 minutes on my box.

```
def nar(width):
    from decimal import Decimal as D
    import decimal
    decimal.getcontext().prec = width + 10
    if width * 9**width < 10**(width - 1):
        raise ValueError("impossible at %d" % width)
    pows = [D(i) ** width for i in range(10)]
    mintotal, maxtotal = D(10)**(width - 1), D(10)**width - 1

    def extend(d, todo, total):
        # assert d > 0
        powd = pows[d]
        d1 = d-1
        powd1 = pows[d1]
        L = total + powd1 * todo # largest possible taking no d's
        dL = powd - powd1  # the change to L when i goes up 1
        for i in range(todo + 1):
            if i:
                total += powd
                todo -= 1
                L += dL
                digitcount[d] += 1
            if total > maxtotal:
                break
            if L < mintotal:
                continue
            if total < mintotal or L > maxtotal:
                yield from extend(d1, todo, total)
                continue
            # assert mintotal <= total <= L <= maxtotal
            t1 = total.as_tuple().digits
            t2 = L.as_tuple().digits
            # assert len(t1) == len(t2) == width
            # Every possible continuation has sum between total and
            # L, and has a full-width sum.  So if total and L have
            # some identical leading digits, a solution must include
            # all such leading digits.  Count them.
            c = [0] * 10
            for a, b in zip(t1, t2):
                if a == b:
                    c[a] += 1
                else:
                    break
            else:  # the tuples are identical
                # assert d == 1 or todo == 0
                # assert total == L
                # This is the only sum we can get - no point to
                # recursing.  It's a solution iff each digit has been
                # picked exactly as many times as it appears in the
                # sum.
                # If todo is 0, we've picked all the digits.
                # Else todo > 0, and d must be 1:  all remaining
                # digits must be 0.
                digitcount[0] += todo
                # assert sum(c) == sum(digitcount) == width
                if digitcount == c:
                    yield total
                digitcount[0] -= todo
                continue
            # The tuples aren't identical, but may have leading digits
            # in common.  If, e.g., "9892" is a common prefix, then to
            # get a solution we must pick at least one 8, at least two
            # 9s, and at least one 2.
            if any(digitcount[j] < c[j] for j in range(d, 10)):
                # we're done picking digits >= d, but don't have
                # enough of them
                continue
            # for digits < d, force as many as we need for the prefix
            newtodo, newtotal = todo, total
            added = []
            for j in range(d):
                need = c[j] - digitcount[j]
                # assert need >= 0
                if need:
                    newtodo -= need
                    added.append((j, need))
            if newtodo < 0:
                continue
            for j, need in added:
                newtotal += pows[j] * need
                digitcount[j] += need
            yield from extend(d1, newtodo, newtotal)
            for j, need in added:
                digitcount[j] -= need
        digitcount[d] -= i

    digitcount = [0] * 10
    yield from extend(9, width, D(0))
    assert all(i == 0 for i in digitcount)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from datetime import datetime
    start_t = datetime.now()
    width = total = 0
    while True:
        this_t = datetime.now()
        width += 1
        print("\nwidth", width)
        for t in nar(width):
            print("   ", t)
            total += 1
        end_t = datetime.now()
        print(end_t - this_t, end_t - start_t, total)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is to generate similar numbers. For example, 61 is similar to 16 as you are just summing

> 6^n +1^n

so

> 6^n+1^n=1^n+6^n

In this way you can reduce significant amount of numbers. For example in 3 digits scenario,

> 121==112==211,

you get the point. You need to generate those numbers first.
And you need to generate those numbers without actually iterating from 0-n.

Comment: I don't think that will help. 153 is narcissistic, but that means that 135, 513, 531, 315 and 351 **can't** be narcissistic.

Answer (score 1):

**Python version is:**

```python
def generate_power_list(power):
return [i**power for i in range(0,10)]


def find_narcissistic_numbers_naive(min_length, max_length):
for number_length in range(min_length, max_length):

    power_dict = generate_power_dictionary(number_length)

    max_number = 10 ** number_length
    number = 10** (number_length -1)
    while number < max_number:

        value = 0
        for digit in str(number):
            value += power_dict[digit]

        if value == number:
            logging.debug('narcissistic %s ' % number)

        number += 1
```

**Recursive solution:**

In this solution each recursion handles a single digit of the array of digits being used, and tries all appropriate combinations of that digit

```python
def execute_recursive(digits, number_length):
index = len(digits)
if digits:
    number = digits[-1]
else:
    number = 0
results = []
digits.append(number)    

if len(digits) < number_length:
    while number < 10:
        results += execute_recursive(digits[:], number_length)
        number += 1
        digits[index] = number

else:
    while number < 10:
        digit_value = sum_digits(digits)
        if check_numbers_match_group(digit_value, digits):
            results.append(digit_value)
            logging.debug(digit_value)

        number += 1
        digits[index] = number

return results


def find_narcissistic_numbers(min_length, max_length):
for number_length in range(min_length, max_length):
    digits = []
    t_start = time.clock()
    results = execute_recursive(digits, number_length)
    print 'duration: %s for number length: %s' %(time.clock() - t_start, number_length)
```

**Narcissistic number check**
In the base version, when checking that a number matched the digits, we iterated through each digit type, to ensure that there were the same number of each type. In this version we have added the optimisation of checking the digit length is correct before doing the full check.

I expected that this would have more of an effect on small number lengths, because as number length increases, there will tend to be more numbers in the middle of the distribution. This was somewhat upheld by the results:

1. n=16: 11.5% improvement
2. n=19: 9.8% improvement

```python
def check_numbers_match_group(number, digits):
number_search = str(number)

# new in v1.3
if len(number_search) != len(digits):
    return False

for digit in digit_list:
    if number_search.count(digit[0]) != digits.count(digit[1]):
        return False

return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [Multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) for some optimisation of cheacking if it is Narcissistic number.
you can calculate (a+b+c+..)^n- sum of non n-th powers values
for example for n=2 you should compare x and (a+b)^2-2*a*b where a and b is digits of number x

Comment: the problem is not in the power, as i said powers is already calculated, the problem is in the algorithm to search all numbers in a specific range.

Answer (score -2):

```
'''We can use Nar() function to calculate the Narcissitic Number.'''

import math
def Nar(num):
   sum=0
   n=len(str(num))
   while n>0:
     temp=num%10
     sum=sum+math.pow(temp,n)
     num=num/10
   return sum
x=input()
y=Nar(x)
if x==y:
  print x,' is a Narcissistic number'
else:
 print x,' is not a Narcissistic number'
```