# Correct my thinking in this C exercise

Tags: c, algorithm

The exercise asks to find which of the numbers from 1 to 500, the sum of the numbers specific digits, raised to the third power equals that particular number.

for example 1^3=1
and 371 makes 3^3+7^3+1^3 = 371

How I approached the problem:

I was thinking if I could have an array of strings with 500 slots, each slot containing a string converted number, then I could do math with each slot's string. If they met the criteria I would apply then that slot would be printed.

I tried the function sprintf without much success. In a loop it just initializes the strings (or is it arrays? after 3 hours I am confused) [0] slot, leaving all other slots unchanged.

I don't want you to solve the exercise, rather than guide me with my logic. Please ask me to add code of what I did if you want to.

Comment: The best way how to confront your idea is to implement it and find out how it's working. Then later when you will face some specific problem, you might come back here and ask again.

Comment: First write a function which takes a number as input argument, and tells you whether the number satisfies the specified criteria or not by returning 1 or 0 respectively.

Comment: It's good that you wrote some ideas about how it could be solved, but people here want to see what you have actually tried.

Comment: Please don't use strings to solve a math problem. You'll run out of memory and CPU time quickly. Use modulo arithmetic and integer division to get a particular digit from a number.

Comment: 0, 1, 153, 370, 371 and 407 are only numbers from 1 to 500. Print them directly ;)

Comment: I'll come back after I get some sleep. I puzzled myself that much, I can't think straight anymore :( I spent more than 3 hours so far. H2CO3 good idea. I really haven't thought of that!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140960/how-to-generate-narcissistic-numbers-faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always start by clearly defining your algorithm, so you know what you are doing. Split it up into simple steps. Something like this:

```
For each integer i in the interval 1 to 500:
  Check if the condition holds for this i
  If it holds:
    Print i
  else:
    Do nothing
```

Now you need to define "*Check if the condition holds for this i*". I would use some modulo and division arithmetics to extract the digits, but I leave the details to you.

Note that I have talked nothing about C or any other programming language. Only when you know your algorithm should you start thinking about implementation.

(There is actually the possibility of a slightly different algorithm than the one given above, where you have one loop for each digit nested inside each other. That solution may be acceptable to you but it will not be as generic)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=1;i<=500;i++)
{
   //loop for checking each number i
   int sum=0; // to store the sum of cube of digits
   int n=i; //copy of i
   //The below while loops does the task. It extracts a digit from the number and adds its cube to the sum
   // last digit from the number can be seen by taking its remainder by 10 . For eg 35%10=5
   //once we have used this digit make the number shorter by dividing by 10. For eg 35/10 becomes 3 (because of integer divisions)
   while(n>0)
   {
       int rem=n%10; //extract the last digit
       sum+=cube(rem); //cube function raises a number to its cube
       n/=10;  //remove the digit we had extracted earlier from the number
    }
    if(sum==i) //we got the number we wanted
        printf("%d\n",i);

}
```